# autolayout uiscrollview how to control the content inset

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a problem with UIScrollView Autolayout. Scrolling works but the scrolling area size is small. If I use

```
self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInset(0,0,120,0);
```

it works for 6+ but doesn't work with other devices. So, I want to fix it with Autolayout. Here is my current Autolayout configuration:[image: Autolayout Configuration]. The label is multiline. Other than the Autolayout constraints and the snippet above, I have not written anything.

Comment: Have you set UIScrollView's contentSize property?

Comment: Doesn't adding the content constraints for the scroll view actually set up the content size?

Comment: I have never managed to get that working properly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, what you should really do is set the scrollviews contentSize property, so for you it would look something like...

```
theScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height)
```

Comment: This kills the purpose of using autolayout for scroll view content size.